# Generating second graph in different window - VPython

Tags: python, graph, vpython

If I have a graph like this in VPython: graphX = gcurve(color = color.cyan), how can I make another graph (graphY = gcurve(color = color.red)) in a different window (different set of axes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use gdisplay() to create graph window:

```
from visual.graph import *
graphX = gcurve(color = color.cyan)
gdisplay()
graphY = gcurve(color = color.red)
```

Comment: I was actually using gdisplay(), but the reason it wasn't working for me was because I thought I had to call gdisplay before I plotted the points, not before the gcurve() was created.